# JAXB: getter on a fixed value

Tags: java, xsd, jaxb, schema, unmarshalling

How get I have JAXB create a getter for a fixed attribute?

```
<xs:attribute name="version" type="xs:string" fixed="1.2">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:appinfo>
            <jx:property fixedAttributeAsConstantProperty="true"/>
        </xs:appinfo>
    </xs:annotation>
</xs:attribute>
```

it will create a constant value after the unmarshalling.
    public final static String VERSION = "1.2";

Comment: use xjc tool to build parser based on your xsd document.

Comment: It is creating a static variable that I can get access with the object. Never mind...